# How do I use retryWhen in this particular use case?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, reactivex

Ok so I have this interesting use case. I need to retry an HTTP call in a particular condition, where status code for the last call is 501. Retry should happen 5 times. If it fails, just come back to the error handler in the component. (This is working)

I actually have this working, but here is the scenario. I also need to cater to different status codes in different ways. For example, when status code is 502 or 503, I need a popup. These different scenarios are handled by the function `this.buyPrepaidMobileService.handlebuyPrepaidMobileError` in which I need to pass the status code. But I don't know how can I retrieve this back in my error handler inside the component.

Here is my code:

**In the component:**

```
buyPrepaidMobile(data) {
  this.loader.startLoading();
  this.buyPrepaidMobileService.onBuyPrepaidMobile(data).subscribe(
    response => {
      this.buyPrepaidMobileService.handlebuyPrepaidMobileSuccess(response)
        this.activeStep = 3;
        this.progressIndicator.setStep(3);
        this.loader.stopLoading();
    },
    error => {          
      this.loader.startLoading();
      //This is where I need to handle the other status codes
      this.buyPrepaidMobileService.handlebuyPrepaidMobileError(error.header.statuscode)
      this.activeStep = 3;
      this.progressIndicator.setStep(3);
      this.loader.stopLoading();
      console.log('Retried 5 times, ended with failure');
    }
  )
}
```

**In my Service:**

```
return this.prepaidPaymentProxyService.performAirtimePrepaidPayment(request)
  .retryWhen(error => {
    return error
      .flatMap((error: any) => {
          if (error.header.statuscode  === '501') {
            console.log(++count);
            return Observable.of(error).delay(1000)
          }
          return Observable.throw(error);
       }).take(5).concat(Observable.throw(error));
    })
```

Now here is my problem. In my component, I need the error object to get the status code. However, by doing it this way, I am getting back a subject. And I don't know how to retrieve the status code out of it.

Can anyone please help me by pointing out what I am doing wrong? If the status code is not 501, I need the error object inside my component, so that I can handle different status codes in different ways.

Any help is appreciated :)